# Order of affine transformations on matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am trying to solve the following question:

[image]

Apparently the correct answer to the question is (a) but I can't seem to figure out why that is the case.

The only way I can seem to replicate the matrix is to first do a translation by (-2,2) and then rotating by 90 degrees. However, the answer says that:

> M represents a translation of vector **(2,2)** followed by a rotation of angle 90 degrees transform

If it is a translation of (2,2), then why does the matrix M not contain (2,2,1) in its last column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to do the calculation in a computer algebra system (Octave):

First the translation:

```
>> T = [ 1,0,2; 0,1,2; 0,0,1]
T =

   1   0   2
   0   1   2
   0   0   1
```

Then the rotation by $90^\circ$:

```
>> R = [ 0, -1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0,0,1]
R =

   0  -1   0
   1   0   0
   0   0   1
```

Finally the composition of the two, applying first $T$ then $R$:

```
>> R*T
ans =

   0  -1  -2
   1   0   2
   0   0   1
```

So this is a consequence of performing the matrix multiplication with this specific $R$.

Comment: Why do you do R*T instead of T*R? I thought the translation is done first?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that, could you please explain?

Comment: We are using column vectors here, and so a transformation works by multiplying the transformation matrix from  the right with the column vector, e.g. $u' = T u$ would be the translated vector. Which then gets rotated: $u'' = R u' = R (T u) = (R  T) u$.  For row vectors it would be the other way round. Note: I changed the vectors to $u$, so you do not confuse it with the $x$ coordinate.

Comment: Ah, so for this particular example we would need to apply the transformation of the rightmost matrix first and then move leftwards? I see, thank you!

Comment: For column vectors consecutive transformations stack right to left, for row vectors they stack left to right. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors#Preferred_input_vectors_for_matrix_transformations). Both systems are connected by transposition: $x' = B A x$ now we transpose both sides and get $x'^\top = x^\top A^\top B^\top$.